# Error parser python read csv data using numpy

Tags: python, csv

I have this kind of error in jupyter notebook, is there something needs to be done?

[image: error]

---

ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_15164\57077545.py in 
----> 1 pd.read_csv('datawisata.csv', skip_blank_lines=False)

apparently i have blank data from my travel.csv.

[image: this is view of the blank]

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 54, saw 2

any suggestions how to parse it ??
or maybe it can't be done so i need to change it into 'blank' words first?

Comment: You cut most of the error. Please don't use images but post formatted text into the question

Comment: Can you include a few lines of your input file?

Comment: You still didn't post the actual error...

Comment: This shouldn't be so hard. Please post a [mre] of your code, the file and the full error you get. No images

Comment: thankyou @Tomerikoo i edited the question, sorry :)) the error is quite long, but the end i got this : ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 54, saw 2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas Error tokenizing data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18039057/6045800)

Comment: Yess as your reference says there is coma in my data that causing error when parsing the data. thankyou

Comment: Then mark it as duplicate or just delete the question. It is unclear and brought unrelated answers so it is not likely to help anyone else

Answer (score -1):

first thing this is pandas not numpy :p

second, you can keep blanck cells in pandas as empty string with the parameter `keep_default_na=False` as you can see in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43832955/12172630)

you can do similarly in numpy as answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73486425/12172630)

Comment: The code is not even able to read the file so this has nothing to do with it...